# How can i add another line to make this a multi line chart?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, web

I have trying to add another graph line to show another set of data. I am struggling to add another line of data. the technologies i am using are, D3.js, HTML and CSS.

Could someone help me with adding another line of data into this graph please?

CSS -

```
<style>

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
    </style>
```

and this is my D3.js to create the graph.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>



<script>

    var arrData = [
    ["2012-10-02",200],
    ["2012-10-09", 300], 
    ["2012-10-12", 150]];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;


var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width])

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var data = arrData.map(function(d) {
      return {
         date: parseDate(d[0]),
         close: d[1]
      };

  });

  console.log(data);


  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Price ($)");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that would be really simple, since you already done the job. The working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w4yxqnbg/7/) and what I did was simply copying your pieces of code according to the new data `arrData2`

Given a new data:

```
var arrData2 = [
    ["2012-10-02",250],
    ["2012-10-09", 200], 
    ["2012-10-12", 100]
];
```

You just have to adjust your data, as you did before:

```
var data2 = arrData2.map(function(d) {
      return {
         date: parseDate(d[0]),
         close: d[1]
      };    
});
```

And add a new line according to `data2`:

```
svg.append("path")
      .datum(data2)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look a this, however i tried what you suggested and it is not working for me. Are you able to to put your solution on js bin or a js fiddle please? If you don't mind.

Comment: If you're starting to learn `d3`, I suggest you to follow this great book: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3, and if my answer helped you, I'd appreciate an upvote =D

Comment: i will take a look at the link that you have provided, i will for sure give you an upvote. Have you linked your suggestion to my original post because when i followed your suggestion it never worked for me

Comment: Oh sorry, i just saw you created a js fiddle for me. Thank you so much